# JS Retrieve object from array and convert it to a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm creating a loop that takes a name and compares it to all the values in an array and stops and prints the name and number when it matches its value. Since the values are objects, I'm trying to convert the object to a string using toString() but it only returns [object Undefined] for me.

```
let name = 'Mustafa';
let i = 0;
let para = document.createElement('p');

let phonebook = [
  { name : 'Chris', number : '1549' },
  { name : 'Li Kang', number : '9634' },
  { name : 'Anne', number : '9065' },
  { name : 'Francesca', number : '3001' },
  { name : 'Mustafa', number : '6888' },
  { name : 'Tina', number : '4312' },
  { name : 'Bert', number : '7780' },
  { name : 'Jada', number : '2282' },
]

i = 0
while (i < phonebook.length) {
  if (i === 4) {
  para.textContent = toString(phonebook[i]);
  } else {}

i++;
}

let section = document.querySelector('section');
section.appendChild(para);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a while loop for that, use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

And use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to display the result or [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the object :

```js
let name = "Mustafa";

let para = document.createElement("p");

let phonebook = [
  { name: "Chris", number: "1549" },
  { name: "Li Kang", number: "9634" },
  { name: "Anne", number: "9065" },
  { name: "Francesca", number: "3001" },
  { name: "Mustafa", number: "6888" },
  { name: "Tina", number: "4312" },
  { name: "Bert", number: "7780" },
  { name: "Jada", number: "2282" }
];

let obj = phonebook.find(e => e.name === name);

para.textContent = `name : ${obj.name} , number : ${obj.number}`;

// OR
// para.textContent = JSON.stringify(obj);

let section = document.querySelector("section");
section.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using JavaScript find method you can get the object that matches the name.

```
const contact = phonebook.find(item => item.name === name);
```